# Unable to recognise an Xpath element in selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

Having a little issue when trying to find an element using selenium c sharp (hash tag not working).

I have this element:

```
<div class="confirmation-price-summary__price-label underline">
    Travel essentials 
</div>
```

I also have another element which is exactly the same but has a different text associated with it:

```
    <div class="confirmation-price-summary__price-label underline">
    Transfer
</div>
```

I want to find the one that contains the 'Travel essentials' so I written the code below to try and find it:

```
public static By TravelEssentialsBasketLink => By.XPath("//div[text()[contains(.,'Travel essentials')] and [@class='confirmation-price-summary__price-label underline']");
```

However, it states it is not a valid xpath, how can I retrieve this element correctly?

Thanks

Comment: do you have a need to get or potentially get all those elements or are you specifically interested in only the 1 element?

Comment: @socalcheesehead I will need to grab each of those elements at some point in my tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
By.XPath("//div[contains(text(),'Travel essentials') and @class='confirmation-price-summary__price-label underline']");
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Hi, it might be possible there are other div tags that contain 'Travel essentials' as it's text, is there a way to also target it's class to ensure it's exactly right?

Comment: Yes, look at my answer now, I edited it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to need them all at some point or want to operate over the whole set you could grab them all and put them into a list:

```
List<WebElements> elements = driver.findElements(By.Xpath("//div[@class='confirmation-price-summary__price-label underline']");

for(WebElement element : elements) {
    String text = element.getText();
    if(text.equals("blah"))
       do_whatever();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below XPath :

```
By.XPath("//div[contains(text(),'Travel essentials') and @class='confirmation-price-summary__price-label underline']")
```

This will work as in your XPath you are not checking for text correctly.

To check the XPath is returning the correct element or not follow the below steps.

1. Open the page in Chrome browser.
2. Open developer tools by using F12.
3. Now open console and type below command.you will get the elements associated with the corresponding XPath.

   ```
   $x("//div[contains(text(),'Travel essentials') and @class='confirmation-price-summary__price-label underline']")
   ```
4. This command should return the elements associated with the XPath.Before writing the code you can use this to validate the XPath

Answer (score 0):

Please use following xpath for exact text verification while having partial or full class attribute:

```
By.XPath("//div[text()='Travel essentials' and contains(@class,'confirmation-price-summary__price-label')]")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you were pretty much closer with:

```
public static By TravelEssentialsBasketLink => By.XPath("//div[text()[contains(.,'Travel essentials')] and [@class='confirmation-price-summary__price-label underline']");
```

Here I will suggest you to make a small update as follows:

```
public static By TravelEssentialsBasketLink => By.XPath("//div[contains(.,'Travel essentials') and (@class='confirmation-price-summary__price-label underline')]");
```